# Delphi initial value as a function result

Tags: delphi

is it possible to declare a string var and give it the result of a function
as initial value like this or similar :

```
var
 s : string = myfunction();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, but you could do that from the `initialization` section of the unit.

EDIT:

```
var
  s : string;

...

initialization

  s := myfunction();

...
```

Answer (score 7):

No, Delphi language (or Object Pascal, whatever it is called at the moment) doesn't support that.

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to declare an assign the variable separately:

```
var
  s : string;
begin
  s := myfunction(); 
  ...
end;
```